# Bound on cross-covariance given linear mixture of random vectors

Tags: covariance-matrix, linear, mixture-distribution

I have a data model whereby random vector $c = a + b$ with unknown distributions and zero means. I can empirically obtain an estimate of $E[cc^T]$ and $E[bb^T]$. For posterity, $E[cc^T] = E[(a+b)(a+b)^T] = E[aa^T] + E[ab^T] + E[ba^T] + E[bb^T]$. I would like to obtain a lower bound on $\frac{w^TE[aa^T]w}{w^TE[ab^T]w+w^TE[ba^T]w+w^TE[bb^T]w}$, for some given (fixed) vector $w$. Is this possible? Are there any assumptions I can make such that it becomes possible? If it helps, the vectors are sensor-space magnetoencephalography data, and $a$ is unobservable - I can only observe the mixture $c$ or isolate and observe $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $E[cc^T]$ and $E[bb^T]$, the following theorem (in combination with some simple algebra) provides a lower bound without any further assumptions:

[image]

[image]

- Hanebeck, Uwe D., and Kai Briechle. "New results for stochastic prediction and filtering with unknown correlations." Multisensor Fusion and Integration for Intelligent Systems, 2001. MFI 2001. International Conference on. IEEE, 2001.